# Events dynamic value passing

Tags: mysql

My current snippet has added here.

Problem is while doing an insert into mail table that time I have `Triggered Value: lc_calc_value` so `lc_calc_value` should be inserted from `select query` but it's not going to insert value.

Code :

```
CREATE EVENT custom_alert ON SCHEDULE  EVERY 600 SECOND DO 
                                 BEGIN
                                 DECLARE lc_current_time DATETIME;
                                 DECLARE lc_calc_value DECIMAL(8,2);
                                 SET lc_current_time = CONVERT_TZ(NOW(), @@session.time_zone, '+0:00');

                                 SELECT AVG(billseconds) AS calc_value FROM table1 c WHERE c.date >  lc_current_time + INTERVAL -600 SECOND AND c.date <= lc_current_time AND group_id = 7 into lc_calc_value ;
                                 IF lc_calc_value <= 10.00 THEN 
                                    INSERT INTO custom_report(triggered_value,type,status,email,group_od,threshold_value,period,triggered_date) value (lc_calc_value,2,1,'abc.com',7,10.00,600,lc_current_time);
INSERT INTO mail (`date`,`subject`,`body`,`from`,`to`,`status`,`reseller_id`) VALUES (1,lc_current_time,'Alarm : ACD','Hello Admin,
                        Name : ACD,
                        Type : Gateway,
                        Threshold : 10.00
                        Period : 100
                        Trunk/CLI : new_test 
                        Triggered Value : lc_calc_value','abc@ghi.com','abc.com',1,0);      
                                 END IF;
```

Comment: You'd better mention the platform that you use. But I reckon the usage is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Is there already an entry in "custom_report" with the same PK?
Also your insert looks wrong. When I read it, you try to insert:

```
mail.date = 1
mail.subject = lc_current_time
mail.body = "Alarm...
...
```

I assume you messed up the query.